# TSQL Count function and distinct missing NULL values

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql, count

According to MSDN, the TSQL COUNT(*) function includes any NULL values in the result unless DISTINCT is also used (source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx)

However, in my query NULL values are being ignored. To test this, I created a small table and filled it with some data:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (colA varchar(1), colB varchar(10))
INSERT tbl VALUES
('Y', 'test1'),
('Y', 'test2'),
(null, 'test3'),
(null, 'test4'),
('N', 'test5')
```

I then ran the following 2 queries on it:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM tbl
WHERE colA <> 'N'
```

and

```
SELECT DISTINCT colA FROM tbl
WHERE colA <> 'N'
```

Both results ignore the NULL values. I get 2 and 'Y' as the results respectively. I'm at a loss to why this is happening. Could someone please clue me in?

Results simulated in SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8f00b/9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @tbl as Table (colA varchar(1), colB varchar(10)) 
insert @tbl values 
  ('Y', 'test1'), ('Y', 'test2'), (null, 'test3'), (null, 'test4'), ('N', 'test5')
select * from @tbl

select
  count(*) as 'Rows', -- All rows.
  count(colA) as [colA Values], -- Rows where   colA   is not NULL.
  count(colB) as [colB Values],  -- Rows where   colB   is not NULL.
  count(distinct colA) as [Distinct colA], -- Number of distinct values in   colA .
  count(distinct colB) as [Distinct colB], -- Number of distinct values in   colB .
  -- NULL never equals anything, including another NULL.
  case when 42 = NULL then 'Yes' else 'Unknown' end as [Answer Is NULL?],
  case when NULL = NULL then 'Yes' else 'Unknown' end as [NULL = NULL],
  -- Use   is NULL   to explicitly check for   NULL .
  case when NULL is NULL then 'Yes' else 'Unknown' end as [NULL is NULL]
  from @tbl
```

Comment: The most detailed answer. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Nulls are weird.

`null <> 'N'` evaluates to `false`.
`null = 'N'` also evaluates to `false`.

You need to handle null explicitly:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM tbl
WHERE (colA <> 'N') or (colA is null)
```

Answer (score 2):

Any comparison to Null other than IS NULL will fail.  So both Null = 'N' and Null <> 'N' return false.

If you want the nulls included, you need to say

```
WHERE colA <> 'N' or colA IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `NULL` is unknown, the server doesn't know what is the value for it. But try using `IS NULL`

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM tbl
WHERE colA <> 'N' or  
      colA IS NULL
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8f00b/16)

Comment: Hmm.  If the value is null, how is it logically possible that it "may be N or Y"?  If it is null it is decidedly neither of those values.

Comment: The idea is that null is used to represent "unknown". If the value is "unknown", then it could be N or Y

Comment: But it is not "unknown" (in the sense of maybe being N or Y).  It is *known* to be "undefined".

Comment: From what I discovered yesterday, John is right. It doesnt matter what null us supposed to mean. The fact is, SQL has defined the IS/IS NOT operator to search for null. the =/<> operator doesn't work for it.

Answer (score 2):

```
 select count(IsNull(colA,'')) as colA, count(colB) as colB from @tbl
```

should also do the trick

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `ISNULL` function:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM tbl
WHERE isnull(colA,'F') <> 'N'
```

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933210(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: Yeah you're right. I found out yesterday that its not the count(*) function but the where clause thats excluding the nulls.